# check a folder in SharePoint document library is empty or not using SharePoint designer workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a SharePoint document library. In that some of the folder doesn't contain any item (empty)

How to check the folder is empty or not using SharePoint Designer Workflow.

If the folder is empty I want to show a pop-up to alert the user the folder is empty.

How it will achieve.

Note: The redirection to particular document library is through the link from mail. (if the status is Approved then email will send)

Thanks in advance.... please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Current item's  Itemchildcount and FolderChildCount properties to check if the folder is empty.

[image]

Then maybe you can have an additional field on your folder content type to flag if the dialog box will pop up. You can update this flag if ItemChildCount is zero then when you view the folder you can check that field with a piece of JavaScript to pop up the dialog?

Comment: Thank you Ova,, but i cant able to see "Item Child Count" in sharepoint designer

Comment: which version of SharePoint please.

Comment: SharePoint designer workflow 2013 , it will not possible i think

Comment: Hi, When I create a 'List Workflow' on a Document library,
 add Condition "If current item field equals value"  I can see it under the fields listed. That is on a SP 2013 site.

Comment: I cant see that,, do we need to activate any feature for that??

Comment: Please use SharePoint Workflow 2010 Template for this